# How to download the artifactory by parsing AQL using curl script?

Tags: curl, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am using curl for downloading the latest artifactory from the repository and then want to download it to my server.. How can I achieve that. I am using the following command for getting AQL.

> curl -u 'uname:pwd' -X PUT
>   https://testrepo.test.test/artifactory/api/search/aql -d 'items.find
>   ({"repo":"snapshots"},{"name":{"$match":"test*.war"}}).sort({"$desc" :
>   ["created"]}).limit(3)' -H "Content-Type: text/plain"

Following is the AQL I get -

> { "results" : [ {   "repo" : "snapshots",   "path" :
>   "******-SNAPSHOT",   "name" : "*****.war",   "type" : "file",   "size"
>   : 63059101,   "created" : "2018-05-31T08:39:11.353-05:00",
>   "created_by" : "***_user",   "modified" :
>   "2018-05-31T08:39:09.724-05:00",   "modified_by" : "****_user",
>   "updated" : "2018-05-31T08:39:09.724-05:00" } ], "range" : {
>   "start_pos" : 0,   "end_pos" : 1,   "total" : 1,   "limit" : 3 } }

How can I download the artifacts by parsing this AQL using Curl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI), which is free CLI tool by JFrog. 
By doing so you can "ask" the CLI to [download the artifact/s](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-Download,CopyandMoveCommandsSpecSchema) base on an AQL search, which means that all you have to do is specify the same AQL query and the CLI will resolve it for you.